# make error when build symbian application with bullseye coverage

Tags: symbian, bullseye

**I want to build a symbian application with bullseye coverage to collect the coverage data. After I finished my application, built the libcov-symbian.lib and enabled the cov01, I built my workspace and got the make error. I've searched some method on the internet, but none worked. The following is the build information:**

---

```
***Building project "HelloWorld" for configuration "Phone Debug (ARMV5) [S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0]"

***Printing environment variables modified from default:
PATH=C:\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools;C:\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\gcc\bin;C:/Symbian/Tools/Carbide.c++ v3.2/jre/bin/client;C:/Symbian/Tools/Carbide.c++ v3.2/jre/bin;C:/Symbian/Tools/Carbide.c++ v3.2/jre/lib/i386;C:\BullseyeCoverage\bin;C:\Carbide.c++ v3.2\x86Build\Symbian_Tools\Command_Line_Tools;C:\Perl\bin\;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\CSL Arm Toolchain\bin;C:\Program Files\CSL Arm Toolchain\bin;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Access Connections\;D:\Program Files\PICT\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\DEV-CPP\Bin;C:\python32\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;c:\android-2.2\tools;C:\Program Files\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin;\epoc32\tools\sbs\bin;C:\Program Files\ant1.8.2\bin;c:\RVCT22;\epoc32\tools\sbs\bin;C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\sbs\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Symbian\tools;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools
EPOCROOT=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\
NO_DEPENDENCIES=-nd
MAKE=make -j 4

Working Directory: C:/Symbian/Carbide/workspace/HelloWorld/group

***Makefile structures up to date. Skipping 'bldmake bldfiles'

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ export  
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\EXPORT.make" EXPORT VERBOSE=-s
Nothing to do

Total Time: 0 sec

***Generating abld makefile.

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ makefile armv5 Icons_scalable_dc  
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ARMV5.make" MAKEFILEICONS_SCALABLE_DC VERBOSE=-s
make -j 4 -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group -f "ICONS_SCALABLE_DC.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\ICONS_SCALABLE_DC\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 MAKMAKE

Total Time: 0 sec

***Generating abld makefile.

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ makefile armv5 build_help  
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ARMV5.make" MAKEFILEBUILD_HELP VERBOSE=-s
make -j 4 -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP -f "BUILD_HELP.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\BUILD_HELP\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 MAKMAKE
Converting rtf files to .ptml.xml

Converting .ptml.xml files to .csptml.xml

Converting .csptml.xml files to .asptml.xml

Converting .cust.xml file to .cshlp.xml

Converting .asptml.xml files to .cshlp.xml

processingC:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP\custom.xml
processingC:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP\HelloWorld.xml
Converting cshlp file to EPOCHelp file

C:\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\release\winc\urel\cshlpwtr "-ifC:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP\temp\HelloWorld_0xea55a455.cshlp.xml" "-ofC:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP\HelloWorld_0xea55a455.hlp"

Extracting contexts into a cpp header file C:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP\HelloWorld_0xea55a455.hlp.hrh

Total Time: 1 sec

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ library armv5  
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ARMV5.make" LIBRARY VERBOSE=-s
make -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group -f "ICONS_SCALABLE_DC.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\ICONS_SCALABLE_DC\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 LIB
make -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP -f "BUILD_HELP.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\BUILD_HELP\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 LIB
make -s  -r -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\HELLOWORLD.ARMV5" LIBRARY

Total Time: 1 sec

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ resource armv5 udeb  
过程试图写入的管道不存在。
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ARMV5.make" RESOURCE CFG=UDEB VERBOSE=-s
make -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group -f "ICONS_SCALABLE_DC.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\ICONS_SCALABLE_DC\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 CFG=UDEB RESOURCE
MifConv version 1.11 build (50, SVG stand-alone).
Checking: ..\gfx\qgn_menu_HelloWorld.svg
Choosing...
Used from: \S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\SVGTBINENCODE.exe.
Convert files...
.
Loading mif icons...
Loading file: \S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\BUILD\s60\icons\temp\s6is.tmp\.._gfx_qgn_menu_HelloWorld.svgb
Writing mif: \S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\data\z\resource\apps\HelloWorld_0xea55a455.mif
make -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP -f "BUILD_HELP.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\BUILD_HELP\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 CFG=UDEB RESOURCE
make -s  -r -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\HELLOWORLD.ARMV5" RESOURCEUDEB

Created \S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\include\HelloWorld_0xea55a455.rsg

Creating \s60\devices\s60_5th_edition_sdk_v1.0\epoc32\build\symbian\carbide\workspace\helloworld\group\helloworld\armv5\udeb

Total Time: 3 sec

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ target armv5 udeb  
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ARMV5.make" TARGET CFG=UDEB VERBOSE=-s
make -j 4 -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group -f "ICONS_SCALABLE_DC.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\ICONS_SCALABLE_DC\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 CFG=UDEB BLD
make -j 4 -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP -f "BUILD_HELP.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\BUILD_HELP\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 CFG=UDEB BLD
make -j 4 -s  -r -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\HELLOWORLD.ARMV5" UDEB
helloworld.cpp
helloworldapplication.cpp
helloworldappview.cpp
helloworldappui.cpp
BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.2.0 Windows License 3349 
Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2011
BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.2.0 Windows License 3349 
Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2011
BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.2.0 Windows License 3349 
Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2011
BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.2.0 Windows License 3349 
Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2011
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 54: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave, TUint aExtraSize);
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 53: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TUint aExtraSize) throw ();
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 52: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave);"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 54: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave, TUint aExtraSize);
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 53: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TUint aExtraSize) throw ();
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 52: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave);
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/f32file.h", line 2976: Warning:  #68-D: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign
   EFsSessionFlagsAll = KSet32,
                        ^
C:\Users\PHOENI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\covc-9b42c7bb\helloworldapplication.cpp: 4 warnings, 0 errors

                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/f32file.h", line 2976: Warning:  #68-D: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign
   EFsSessionFlagsAll = KSet32,
                        ^
C:\Users\PHOENI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\covc-b5df7cb1\helloworld.cpp: 4 warnings, 0 errors
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 53: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave, TUint aExtraSize);
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 52: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TUint aExtraSize) throw ();
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 51: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave);
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/f32file.h", line 2976: Warning:  #68-D: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign
   EFsSessionFlagsAll = KSet32,
                        ^
C:\Users\PHOENI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\covc-5d08d0e\helloworldappview.cpp: 4 warnings, 0 errors
C:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HelloWorldApplication.d does not exist
make[1]: *** [\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\udeb\HelloWorldApplication.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Deleting file `\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\udeb\HelloWorldApplication.o'
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
C:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HelloWorld.d does not exist
make[1]: *** [\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\udeb\HelloWorld.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Deleting file `\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\udeb\HelloWorld.o'
C:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HelloWorldAppView.d does not exist
make[1]: *** [\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\udeb\HelloWorldAppView.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Deleting file `\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\HELLOWORLD\ARMV5\udeb\HelloWorldAppView.o'
make: *** [TARGETHELLOWORLD] Error 2
"\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\src\helloworldappui.cpp", line 194: Warning:  #1215-D: #warning directive: "Please see comment about help and UID3..."
  #warning "Please see comment about help and UID3..."
   ^
\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\src\helloworldappui.cpp: 1 warning, 0 errors
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 53: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave, TUint aExtraSize);
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 52: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TUint)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TUint aExtraSize) throw ();
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/e32base.h", line 51: Warning:  #830-D: function "CBase::operator new(TUint, TLeave)" has no corresponding operator delete (to be called if an exception is thrown during initialization of an allocated object)
   inline TAny* operator new(TUint aSize, TLeave);
                ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/f32file.h", line 2976: Warning:  #68-D: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign
   EFsSessionFlagsAll = KSet32,
                        ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/eiklbx.h", line 575: Warning:  #815-D: type qualifier on return type is meaningless
   __declspec(dllimport) CEikScrollBarFrame* const ScrollBarFrame();
                                                   ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/frmvis.h", line 64: Warning:  #68-D: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign
   inline TBool AllVisible()const{if(!cov_v_ec00291b.data[1691])cov_probe_v10(&cov_o_ec00291b,1691);{return iVisible==EFEverythingVisible;}};
                                                                                                                      ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/eikmenup.h", line 236: Warning:  #550-D: variable "err" was set but never used
   TInt err; { err = 0; { ; } try { TTrapHandler* ____t = User::MarkCleanupStack(); ( iExtendedData = new (ELeave) CExtendedItemData() ); User::UnMarkCleanupStack(____t); { ; } } catch (XLeaveException& l) { err = l . GetReason(); { ; } } catch (...) { User::Invariant(); } { ; } };
        ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/eikedwin.h", line 2878: Warning:  #191-D: type qualifier is meaningless on cast type
   {if(!cov_v_ec00291b.data[2021])cov_probe_v10(&cov_o_ec00291b,2021);{ return ((CEikScrollBarFrame* const)iSBFrame); }}
                                                                                 ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/aknmultilinequerycontrol.h", line 133: Warning:  #815-D: type qualifier on return type is meaningless
   const TInt LinePos() const {if(!cov_v_ec00291b.data[2031])cov_probe_v10(&cov_o_ec00291b,2031);{ return iLinePos; }}
              ^
"/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/aknmultilinequerycontrol.h", line 294: Warning:  #815-D: type qualifier on return type is meaningless
   const TInt LinePos() const {if(!cov_v_ec00291b.data[2032])cov_probe_v10(&cov_o_ec00291b,2032);{ return iLinePos; }}
              ^
C:\Users\PHOENI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\covc-7c17bf8a\helloworldappui.cpp: 10 warnings, 0 errors

Total Time: 11 sec

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ final armv5 udeb  
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ARMV5.make" FINAL CFG=UDEB VERBOSE=-s
make -j 4 -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group -f "ICONS_SCALABLE_DC.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\ICONS_SCALABLE_DC\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 CFG=UDEB FINAL
make -j 4 -s  -C \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\HELP -f "BUILD_HELP.MK" TO_ROOT=..\..\..\..\.. EPOCBLD=\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\BUILD_HELP\ARMV5 TO_BLDINF=..\..\..\..\..\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group PLATFORM=ARMV5 CFG=UDEB FINAL

Total Time: 12 sec

***Invoking abld command
perl.exe -S ABLD.PL \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\ test export  
  make -r  -f "\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\EXPORTtest.make" EXPORT VERBOSE=-s
Nothing to do

Total Time: 12 sec

***Build Complete

***Invoking makesis.exe ....
C:\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\makesis.exe C:\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\build\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\group\_resolvedHelloWorld_S60_5_X_v_1_0_0.pkg C:\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\HelloWorld\sis\HelloWorld_S60_5_X_v_1_0_0.sis 
 Error : Cannot find file : C:/S60/devices/S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/HelloWorld_0xea55a455.exe

(27) : error: file I/O fault.
***Non-Zero Status: makesis.exe returned with exit value = 1
Total Time: 12 sec
```

---

please any one thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that the old version bullseye(7.1.6) didn't support the symbian os well. I email the supporters and updated the version to the newest(8.2.2) and everything goes well!